# Does using a true random number as seed result in truely random numbers?

Tags: python, random-seed

Assuming that we are using an automatically thrown 6 side die to generate an integer between 1 and 100. In Python (or in any other programming language for that matter), this [1, 6] integer will be used as the seed value. Will the resulting integer be truly random? If not, what would be the best method to generate such a number from this randomness source?

Comment: What do you mean by "truly random"?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing is ever truly "random", but there are some useful measurements you can do on a random number generator, like generate a bunch of numbers from it and see if they're fairly evenly distributed.  If you generate numbers from 1-100, and you do that 100*100 times, you should expect to see each individual number about 100 times in the final result, and you'd expect the most frequently rolled number to come up only a little more than 100 times.

```
>>> import random
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> c = Counter()
>>> for _ in range(10000):
...     c[random.randint(1, 100)] += 1
...
>>> max(c.values()
123
```

What would a completely *unrandom* number generator look like?  Let's apply the same process but this time instead of `random.randint(1, 100)` we'll just use the same number each time.

```
>>> c = Counter()
>>> for _ in range(10000):
...     c[42] += 1
...
>>> max(c.values())
10000
>>> c
Counter({42: 10000})
```

So very roughly speaking, the higher that max value is, the less random our random number generator is.

Now let's try the method where we seed the RNG each time with a random number from 1-6:

```
>>> c = Counter()
>>> for _ in range(10000):
...     random.seed(random.randint(1, 6))
...     c[random.randint(1, 100)] += 1
...
>>> max(c.values())
5000
>>> c
Counter({31: 5000, 80: 5000})
```

Not great!  Each time you call `random.seed` you're resetting the RNG to a specific state, from which point if you make the same calls to it, it will always return the same sequence of values.  At absolute best you should only expect to get 6 different answers from that `random.randint(1, 100)` call if you're only ever giving it one of 6 possible different seeds immediately beforehand, which would give you a minimum maximum count of 1667.  It turns out the *actual* randomness is worse, because we don't even get 6 possible seeds (since the `random.randint(1, 6)` call is falling into the same determinism trap).

The tl;dr is that if you want an actual pseudorandom sequence of numbers you should not re-seed the RNG.

(edit) Supposing that you are *required* to seed the RNG using only the output of a 6-sided die -- are you allowed to roll the die more than once?  Consider:

```
>>> c = Counter()
>>> for _ in range(10000):
...     random.seed(sum(random.randint(1, 6) * 6**i for i in range(100)))
...     c[random.randint(1, 100)] += 1
...
>>> max(c.values())
128
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this great answer!

Answer (score 3):

No. A (pseudo)random-number generator produces a deterministic cycle of values. The only thing the seed does is determine where in the cycle you *start* retrieving values; it does not alter the cycle itself.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a good python random-number generating module, use the `secrets` module. It's designed for cryptography. For example:

```
import secrets
secrets.randbelow(10)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately a dice is the only thing that I can use in this case.

Comment: @sf99sL what? What do you mean a dice?

Comment: Forgive my English, I didn't know that "dice" was strictly plural. I meant a die. It is automatically rolled, then it's value is detected. I'm trying to generate a larger integer from the detected value. The numbers generated via this method should be distributed more evenly/more "random" compared to an integer generated by the programming language's function.

Comment: Are you only allowed to roll it once?

Answer (score 0):

It won't be truly random, because it is being generated by an algorithm.  However, it is random enough to model things like odds, or for the sake of making a game.

Answer (score 0):

When using the `random` module, [the seed comes from the system time](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.seed) by default, but [`random.randint`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint) can be used to set the seed. Note that to set the seed in this way, the seed used for any initial call to `random.randint` is the system time.

The answer to your question, true randomness is an unachievable ideal, kind of the thermodynamic efficiency. The best way to generate PRNs for most purposes is to fall back to `random`'s default behavior. Setting and managing seeds is typically for dealing with issues related to reproducibility of the generated PRN sequences.